# Assign specific chat ID for telegram group

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot

Trying to assign an chat ID to make my script or bot send a message on specific chat group only, currently on my testing I can interact with my bot using bot message box only, once I send a message my bot will reply to my chat, May I know what I need to modify with my script for me to assign specific chat id so I can communicate with my bot on specific group only?

**My script**

```
function sendText(chatid,text,replymarkup){
var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String (chatid),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(replymarkup)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + BotToken + '/', data);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? `How to add a bot to a group?`, `How to get the chat_id of a group?`, or something else?

Comment: `if(chatid !== 686767686/*your specific chat id*/) return`